# How to create a pivot table in python (pandas)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a table like this:

**train_df:**

```
Sex Target
M   1
M   1
M   1
F   0
F   1
F   0
```

I want to create a pivot chart, so that it can show result some thing like this:

```
Row Labels  Average of Target
   F              0.333333333
   M                   1
```

I have written a code like this:

```
temp2 = train_df.pivot_table(values='Target', index=['Sex'],aggfunc=lambda x: x.map.mean().
```

I am getting errored out as "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mean'". I know that the usage is not correct in the map.mean function. Could you please help me how to eradicate this. Thank you.

Comment: `train_df.groupby('Sex', as_index=False).Target.mean()` why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on the comment, with few more similar ways

```
In [325]: train_df.groupby('Sex', as_index=False).Target.mean()
Out[325]:
  Sex    Target
0   F  0.333333
1   M  1.000000

In [326]: train_df.groupby('Sex').Target.mean().reset_index()
Out[326]:
  Sex    Target
0   F  0.333333
1   M  1.000000

In [327]: train_df.groupby('Sex', as_index=False).agg({'Target': 'mean'})
Out[327]:
  Sex    Target
0   F  0.333333
1   M  1.000000

In [328]: train_df.groupby('Sex', as_index=False).agg({'Target': np.mean})
Out[328]:
  Sex    Target
0   F  0.333333
1   M  1.000000

In [329]: train_df.groupby('Sex', as_index=False).agg('mean')
Out[329]:
  Sex    Target
0   F  0.333333
1   M  1.000000
```

If you insist on having `pivot_table`

```
In [333]: train_df.pivot_table(index='Sex', values='Target', aggfunc='mean').reset_index()
Out[333]:
  Sex    Target
0   F  0.333333
1   M  1.000000
```

Comment: This has worked. I will accept the answer in 7 minutes.Thank you very much for the answer with many other options.